# Как распарсить Stream

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, filestream

Можно ли распарсить поток? То есть получить из него имя файла, путь к файлу, ну и то что лежит в файле(в виде текста конечно)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае такой информации в потоках нет. Эти сущности предоставляют собственно уже содержимое ресурса (например, файла) и некоторые базовые свойства (например, размер, см. свойство `Length` -- однако не все потоки это поддерживают), а также возможность навигации и чтения. Так что все, что вы можете вытянуть из стрима -- собственно его содержимое.

Если же у вас есть именно `FileStream`, то полный путь к файлу, включая имя, можно взять из свойства [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.name(v=vs.110).aspx). Содержимое удобнее всего прочитать через `StreamReader`:

```
using (FileStream stream = ...)
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```